# Bootstrap 3 Responsive menu disappears

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a custom Bootstrap 3 website that utilises the "nav-bar" element. Everything was working fine and dandy. I resized the browser window, bam, a button appeared and clicking on it resulted in the menu showing in a vertical manner.

The next day I decided to compress my bootstrap.css with grunt-uncss, since I have a fairly simple website and use only a fraction of the elements provided. Worked fine, no problems(it went from 132.5 kB to 10), until I tested my responsive menu.

When I click the button, the vertical menu layout briefly flashes and then disappears immediately. I can click the items if I am lightning fast, and they will direct me to the correct page. I guess it flashes for half a second or so, and then, bam, it's gone.

I debugged the problem to being in the bootstrap.css file and not in my custom style.css, because replacing the compressed file with the original makes my menu work normal again.

Does anyone know what elements in bootstrap.css cause this? I tried pasting some elements containing "nav-bar" or ".nav-bar" in the compressed css file, but it didn't work.

Here is the code I wrote that is on every page and creates the nav-bar, with the logo(navbar-brand):

```
   <div id="container">
    <div class="hidden-header"></div>
    <header class="clearfix">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img alt="Logo Puntzeven" src="images/layer3.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Extra</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown">
                                <li><a href="tabs.html">Tabs</a></li>
                                <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        </li>
                                <li><a href="tarieven.html">Tarieven</a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html">Over ons</a></li>
                                <li><a href="services.html">Voorzieningen</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I apologize if I should have been more compact in my question asking, but I wanted to ensure people understood exactly what I did.

I would rather not replace the normal bootstrap.css with the compressed one, if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/mtynydh6/1/)**  
You can do like this way

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse " role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TutorialsPoint</a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               Extra <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">Tabs</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>

              </ul>
         </li>
          <li><a href="tarieven.html">Tarieven</a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html">Over ons</a></li>
                                <li><a href="services.html">Voorzieningen</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>

</nav>
```

add css

```
        .mypanel {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
   }


.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

I didn't copy your content please replace with your content..

Comment: Thank you immensely for the help, but unfortunately it didn't work. The responsive menu still collapses after 0,5 second. Do you have any other input? If not, I guess I'll just have to use the full bootstrap file, so everything works. Thank you!